# Likebutton does'nt work phpacademy - Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Ive been following phpacademy recently and their code simply doesn't work.Well it works fine to the point of displaying the articles but the like button doesn't work, it stops at '$.post' method,its job was to update the article_likes to '22', take a look:
index.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <?php  include 'core/db/connect.php';  ?>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
            $articles = get_articles();
            if(count($articles) == 0)
                echo "No art";
            else{
                //Displaying articles.
                foreach($articles as $article){
                    echo $article['article_title']."<br>";
                    echo "<a onclick=\"like_add(".$article['article_id'].");\" href='#'>Like</a><br>";
                    echo "<span id='article_".$article['article_id']."_likes'>".$article['article_likes']. "</span>Likes<br> ";
                }
            }

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/like.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

like.js

```
            function like_add(article_id){
            $.post('like_add.php',{article_id:article_id},function(data){
                if(data[0] == 'success'){
                    like_get(article_id);
                } else {
                    alert(data[0]);
                }

            });

        }

        function like_get(article_id){
            $.post('like_get.php',{article_id:article_id},function(data){
                $('#article_'+article_id+'_likes').text(data[0]);
            });
        }
```

like_add.php

```
<?php echo "success";?>
```

like_get.php

```
<?php echo "22";?>
```

Comment: Does the file `like_add.php` also exist on the server?

Comment: Yes they are on the same file as like.js

Comment: Why are you using `data[0]` to get the result? As far as I can see, `data` would simply be a string, not an array. You need to debug your code a bit more. Do a `console.log(data)` in the callback and see what you get. You can also check network tab in your browsers dev tools to see what it actually sends to `like_add.php` and what the response is.

Comment: That was just a guess. You really need to explain in much more detail what you mean by “the like button doesn't work”! Is the button displayed? Can you click on the button at all? Is a request sent to `like_add.php`? (see the network-tab in your browsers dev-tools) If a request was sent, what is the response? Or does everythink looks OK, but you just never see the like appear on the article?

Comment: In addition to Magnus's note, if you wanted to use `data[0]`, you need to set .post to expect json (fourth param), and then to `echo json_encode(array('success'));` out as an array with the value in the first index.

Comment: You can also simplify your process by returning the new like count with the first call, so you are not doing two ajax calls in a row.

Comment: i tried what magnus said, nothing gets logged when i console.log at like_add but the network status says '404'....What does that mean?

Comment: 404 means the url you are trying to access does not exist on the server. You previously said that the `like_add.php` is in the same location as `like.js` ... but you didn't mention if `index.php` which uses `like.js` is in the same location. Paths matter. Based on your code above, you have `js/like.js` ... so this means `like_add.php` is also in `js/` ? Ergo, your js of `$.post('like_add.php'...` should be `$.post('js/like_add.php'...` (same for like_get)

Comment: Damn... that was the problem after all thanks man you are a life saver